# Unable to connect to the asp.net development server (vs 2010, win 7 ultimate 64bit, SQL Server 2005)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

Whenever I run a web project (even simple one), I face this error. What should I do?

(Windows 7 64 bit - SQL Server 2005 - Visual Studio 2010 - Avast Business Protection)

Here's the screenshot "http://www.imgplace.com/viewimg155/9347/31unledi.jpg"

Comment: Seems Avast is not allowing it. Try disabling Avast protection. If it works, you need to add exception in the Protection software.

Comment: @Kangkan :I disabled but, no it didn't work - I even uninstall Avast.

Comment: Is your ASP.NET/IIS is registered with .NET? Otherwise use ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe). See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Kangkan: ASP.NET/IIS is registered (screenshot:http://www.imgplace.com/viewimg695/3279/84unled.jpg).